# angular: ResizeObserver not work with innerHTML set from getter

Tags: javascript, angular, innerhtml, resize-observer

demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-thunder-bi5q4?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

I'm trying to use ResizeObserver to observe element set by `[innerHtml]` binding

when I put the HTML string in the component class property, the Resize observer works

```
// the component
class App {
  // ...
  _title = `<div id="oo">oo</div>`;
  title = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._title);
}
// the template
<div [innerHtml]="title"></div>
```

but when I put the HTML string in the component class getter, the Resize observer won't work

```
// the component
class App {
  // ...
  get title() {
    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._title);
  }
  _title = `<div id="oo">oo</div>`;
}

// the template
<div [innerHtml]="title"></div>
```

Comment: But what the ResizeObserver is observing?... The div?... Where is the code that initializes the observer? It will be easier for one to understand your problem if your question have more details. You are asking about ResizeObserver but not showing how you have used it.

Comment: There are a lot of problems on you code. You are trying to initialize the observer inside the ngOnInit before the div has itself been registered on the dom. You are handling the dom directly inside an Angular application and it has a lot of security issues. Do you really need to do this?

Comment: see https://dev.to/christiankohler/how-to-use-resizeobserver-with-angular-9l5, maybe it can help